# LatLng is no longer working in the compiler

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

So I started working on getting my map up and running in my little application and as soon as I tried putting in camera moves and such I ran into a little snag. The compiler doesn't seem to like the `LatLng` class at all. It gives me this.

```
The method LatLng(double, double) is undefined for the type MyMapHandler
```

So I tried `ctrl+alt+o` and that didn't fix it, so I manually added the imports like so:

```
...
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

Doing that fixed the other issues I was getting with `map` classes, but it did not fix the `LatLng(double, double)` not working issue. I'm still getting the above error when I do this

```
public class MyMapHandler extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;

    ...

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                           LatLng(mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude(),
                                  mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()),
                           (float) 4));
    }

    ...
}
```

At this point, I'm not sure what's going on. After manually putting the import in, the context popups seem to work fine with the `LatLng` class, it even pulls up the **JavaDocs** with no problem. So I'm convinced the issue is with eclipse not my code. Although if you see something let me know. I tried searching both bing and google and didn't come up with anything useful. Just people saying "fix my code!!!" and obviously not getting a response.

EDIT: It did work yesterday, so that's part of my confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think one problem might be that you are missing the new keyword prior to the `LatLng` instantiation. Try new `LatLng` inside `newLatLngZoom()`

Comment: Doh. **facepalm** That fixed it. Geez. I've been banging my head for like 2 hours on this. Lol. Time for a break I think.